# How to automate compatibility between JARs using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar, dependencies

My question is about Maven dependencies:

Is there a method that allows me to automate the version compatibility between JARs, i.e. when I add a dependency, Maven will look for the version compatible with the already existing dependencies? If yes, what is this method?

Comment: What would be criteria of compatiblity?

Comment: This might be feasible but may not be the right thing to do. Downgrading or upgrading of versions will generally have lot of implications depending on your code.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no such method/ utility. We resolve the dependency conflicts manually and choose the versions we want.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look here: http://revapi.org/  But this will not automatically look for a dependency version which is compatible...or not...Apart from that if you rely on libs which are vital either you trust the maintainers or you you write integration tests to check the compatibility and can combine that with versions-maven-plugin in a Jenkins setup to automatically upgrade to newer versions and check the constrains based on your integration tests....and of course by using this way you can define the criterias.